# Heightmap from octomap_server?

Tags: ros, octree, ros-indigo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a package which can project a heightmap from registered pointclouds / an octree? Something like projected_map from octomap_server, but with height information instead of occupancy informations?

I would like to create difference images to determine if a floor has gaps or steep edges around the robot. Currently I am using a cut off pointcloud with an occupancy grid to determine if there is a hole in the floor, but I think a gradient image would work better.

If there is no one, could you just use the Z-Value of the leaf boxes of the octree to create one? Is there an easy way to iterrate over them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290391/heightmap-from-octomap_server?/) by [rohezal](https://answers.ros.org/users/34952/rohezal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can convert 3D point cloud data into a 2D elevation map using the [elevation_mapping package](https://github.com/ethz-asl/elevation_mapping). This will allow you calculate the traversability/safety of the map much more easily than the 3D map.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohezal](https://answers.ros.org/users/34952/rohezal/) on 2018-05-04**:
Thank you, this is an ready to use version of thing I wanted to code. Perfect :)